# Automatically resize all pictures uploaded by users, in JetEngine Listing grid

Tags: wordpress, image, resize, jet-engine

Is there a way to ensure that all uploaded pictures by users get posted in same size? So if the picture uploaded doesn't match the resolution it would automatically stretched it out.

I am working in JetEngine with Listing Grids. I still imagine it being Wordpress library that handles the uploaded images.

Thanks in advice!

I've tried to use make.com to resize the images, but the process is long and unstable.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.